# Why isn't Qt gradually changing the opacity of a window in a loop?

Tags: qt, c++11

I'm trying to change the opacity of the window of my program in Qt and using C++11. In other words, I want to open the main Windows slowly by adding some instructions to `main.cpp`. You see those instructons below:

```
MainWindow a;
a.show();

for(int Counter = 0; Counter <= 100; Counter++)
{
    a.SetWindowOpacity(Counter);
    for(Wait = 0; Wait < 100; Wait++);
}
```

But when I build and run my project, I don't see any changes and it normally runs. This is whole source code, `main.cpp`.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.setWindowTitle("Add a new student");
    w.show();

    for(int Counter = 0; Counter <= 100; Counter++)
    {
        w.setWindowOpacity(Counter);
        for(int Wait = 0; Wait < 100; Wait++);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

So, why don't Qt change the opacity of the window of my program?

Answer (score 1):

There are number of issues with your code. First, [setWindowOpacity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) can take values from 0.0 to 1.0, also it does not take `int` but `qreal`, so your loop has to change and look like this:

```
for(qreal Counter = 0.0; qreal <= 1.0; Counter+=0.1)
{
    w.setWindowOpacity(Counter);
}
```

Second, the loop is very fast, so even if it did change the opacity you wouldn't notice it, so if you want to see it visually changing opacity, then you need to add a sleep in between, so your loop will look like this:

```
for(qreal Counter = 0.0; Counter <= 1.0; Counter+=0.1)
{
    w.setWindowOpacity(Counter);
    QThread::msleep(100);
}
```

This will mean that it will change the opacity, wait 100 milliseconds and then change it again.

Third, even if you do all of this, you still won't see anything, since the opacity will change and only after that the event loop will run. And the event loop will run after the `a.exec()` call.

So you have to put your snippet of code somewhere else and after the window is shown. This means you have to call your opacity changing code with delayed execution. The fastest way to do it is with `QTimer`, so your code will look like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.setWindowOpacity(0.0);
  w.show();

  QTimer::singleShot(0, [&] {
    for (qreal i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.01) {
      w.setWindowOpacity(i);
      //The processEvents() call will make sure your app doesn't freeze in the process
      QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
      QThread::msleep(100);
    }
  });

  return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer indicates the cause of the error:

- wrong range of values.
- instant execution that will not make the effect visible, etc.

They also propose to use QTimer but I think a more elegant solution is to use QPropertyAnimation:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Add a new student");
    w.show();

    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation;
    animation->setPropertyName("windowOpacity");
    animation->setTargetObject(&w);
    animation->setStartValue(0.0);
    animation->setEndValue(1.0);
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    return a.exec();
}
```